# what data structure to store for multiple choice test in asp.net on server

Tags: asp.net, data-structures

Are these good answers?

- Array of strings
- Datatable
- Custom Class

What is the best approach?

**EDIT:**

Assume it is multi choice questions (A,B,C,D) and there will few such questions given one at a time.

Comment: "Best" by what criteria?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the type of data you're wanting to store?  It's unclear if you're looking to represent a series of answers to a single question, or an entire test, which might include multiple questions, multiple answers, which answers are correct, etc.

Comment: just edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A collection of custom class would be appropriate for a set of multiple choice questions.
Pseudo Code:

```
class Question {
   public string QuestionText { get; set; }
   public List<Answer> answers {get; set; }
}

class Answer {
    public string AnswerText {get; set;}
    public bool isTheRightAnswer {get; set;} //or something like that or some other properties
}
```

So if you wanted to send more than one questions you could send back

```
List<Question>
```

Comment: Sounds very good for our solutions. thx